# How can I add a Combobox column to a GridControl?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have a grid control that loads data from a DataBase in a desktop Windows Forms application. But I also need a new local column with a combobox (with some items) that when I click it it save the information into another table of the database.
[image]

This is my code

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string conStr = @"Data Source =...;Initial Catalog=...; Integrated Security=true;";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SPS_PronosticoStock2", con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProducto", Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdBodega", Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text));
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaInicio", dateTimePicker1.Value);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaFin", dateTimePicker2.Value);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)

                    con.Close();
            }      
            gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
```

I tried a combobox edit but when i click the items they disappear and nothing is edited, please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer these:
[Unbound Column Combo Box Persistent Value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q249143/unbound-column-combo-box-persistent-value)

Use [Unbound Columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477.aspx). Please review the [Unbound Columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477.aspx) article for more information in this regard.

The best way to get it done is to use [RepositoryItemLookUpEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEdittopic) instead. Just set `theRepositoryItemLookUpEdit.DataSource` property to an appropriate datasource, the `RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.DisplayMember` property - to a column name that should match a display text and the `RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.ValueMember` property - to a column name that should be associated with an edit value.

References:
[Combobox within Xtragrid bound to column value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q304697/combobox-within-xtragrid-bound-to-column-value)
[XtraGrid with comboBox column doesn't save value in grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T365412/xtragrid-with-combobox-column-doesn-t-save-value-in-grid)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbNhg1Xn9O4

Comment: It is the same thing, whenever I select a value of the combobox and I click it or press enter the combobox clears itself and nothing happen, it doesn't stay on the screen

Answer (score -1):

Your values are not being saved, because your column is not bound to a data field. Create an [Unbound Column](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1477/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/unbound-columns#add_columns) and save your values in the [CustomUnboundColumnData](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData) event handler.

Comment: Please, Im a student I dont know how to do that, I already did the unbound part and I gave it a string type. Whenever I put data into the combobox it disappear